# Google Keep: gkeepapi -> can't add labels

Tags: google-keep

Anybody else having trouble with adding labels to notes in `gkeepapi`?

```
import gkeepapi
keep = gkeepapi.Keep()

file = open("C:\\xxxxxxx", "r")
pwd = file.read()
keep.login('xxxxxxxx', pwd)
note = keep.createNote('title', 'text')
note.labels.add('calls')
```

Is giving me this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Jason/Google Drive/pycharm/test.py", line 8, in <module>
    note.labels.add('calls')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\gkeepapi\node.py", line 922, in add
    self._labels[label.id] = label
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'id'
```

Here is the docs. https://gkeepapi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#manipulating-labels-on-notes. I think I'm doing the right thing, but I'm obviously not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say just about *every* bug in the history of computers was caused by someone with the thought "I think I'm doing the right thing" in their head :-)

More seriously, the label that you add to a note is meant to be *label* rather than a string. That's supported by the fact that it's trying to get your label identifier from a string object (which doesn't have one):

> 'str' object has no attribute 'id'

This is actually described in the link you provided, just three sections up from your anchor point:

> **Creating Labels**
>        New labels can be created with `Keep.createLabel()`:
>             `label = keep.createLabel('todo')`
>   `: : blah blah blah`
>   **Manipulating Labels on Notes**
>        When working with labels and notes, the key point to remember is that we’re always working with `node.Label` objects or IDs.

Hence you can create a label and add it to the note with the lines:

```
callLabel = keep.createLabel('calls')
note.labels.add(callLabel)
```

If you *already* have a label with that name, you can get it with:

```
callLabel = keep.findLabel('calls')
```

So, if you wanted to handle both possibilities seemlessly, try to create the label inside a `try/catch` and, if you get an exception, do the find.

Comment: Your code works if there is no label category named `calls` to begin with. if I use your code and the label `calls` is already there. I get this error. `raise exception.LabelException('Label exists')
gkeepapi.exception.LabelException: Label exists`. I'm trying to create a note and put it under the `calls` label without adding a new label for all of Keep.

Comment: @jason: added my suggestion for that. You can try to create a label. On "label already exists" exception, you just find the existing one. Then you add it to your note. On your second point, the bottom line is that there appears to be no way to create a label that exists only for a note, they're Keep-wide resources.

Comment: Bro, I don't think you understand. I'm trying to create a note new and add a label to that new note, for which the label already exists. I don't need to find anything.

Comment: @jason, have you actually *tried* what I suggested in the update? I would suggest you do so. Based on my reading of the doco, this is *exactly* what you need to do. If the label already exists, you need to find it based on the name (using `findLabel`) and then add that label to the new note. You can't just add a string object because, well, it's ***not*** a label.

Comment: You are absolutely right! I'm so sorry. Didn't understand the code. Thanks for being so patient. I thought the find function was to look for a note based on label, but now i get it.

Comment: stack overflow should start a badge that's labeled... "patience in face of stupidity"

Comment: @jason, not stupidity on your part at all. I have a long history teaching people and I realise that often people are 'blinkered' (not able to easily see beyond a certain viewpoint) when they've spent a lot of time on a problem. The trick is to guide them to another path gently. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you try [syncing](https://gkeepapi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#syncing)?

> gkeepapi automatically pulls down all notes after login. It takes care of refreshing API tokens, so there’s no need to call Keep.login() again. After making any local modifications to notes, make sure to call Keep.sync() to update them on the server!:
>
> `keep.sync()`